# Элемент с position:fixed скрывается под панель браузера на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, mobile-web

CSS

```
body {
    outline: none !important;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #404946;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
.fixed-bottom {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    color: #fff !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: left;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body class="shops">
        <div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,.9)" class="text-white fixed-bottom py-1 px-2" id="cookie-law-block">
    Этот сайт использует cookie для хранения данных. Продолжая использовать сайт, Вы даете свое согласие на работу с этими файлами.
            <button class="btn p-1 ml-2" style="font-family:inherit" id="cookie-law-button">Я согласен</button>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Как видно из скриншота, фиксированный блок фиксируется не к низу видимой области окна, а к низу экрана. Как решить эту проблему?
Экспериментальным путем установлено, что  другие элементы на это поведение не влияют. Еще уточню, что при прокрутке вниз скрытая часть блока открывается. Но это все равно странно: задумывалось так, чтобы блок был виден целиком сразу.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Скорее всего блок нужно размещать в элементе, который является "видимой частью экрана", либо задавать смещение (bottom) указывая вышину нижней панели элементов.

Comment: Вышина нижней панели - величина переменная. Какой элемент может являться "видимой частью экрана" кроме body?

Comment: Если нижняя панель, это нативный элемент, то ошибка не в приведённом Вами CSS.

Comment: Да, верно, нативный. Я сейчас попробую собрать и привести все стили относящиеся к body и к этому элементу.